# manipulate POST answers in soap PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have a simple soap server that works great and return answers to the POST requests:

```
<?php

class result extends stdClass
{
    public $ResultCode = '';
    public $ResultDesc = '';
}

class answer
{
  function lgi($a) {
  $data = new result();
  $data->ResultCode = '0';
  $data->ResultDesc = 'Hi';

  return $data;
}
}

$options = array(
'uri' => 'http://loooloo.com/LGI',
'location' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
);
$soap = new SoapServer(null, $options);
$soap->setclass("answer");
$soap->handle();
?>
```

The server sends back:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <ns1:LGIResponse>
  <return 
    xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
    <ResultCode xsi:type="xsd:string">
    0
    </ResultCode>
    <ResultDesc xsi:type="xsd:string">
    Hi
    </ResultDesc>
  </return>
 </ns1:LGIResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

while what I really need is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <LGOResponse>
        <Result>
            <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
            <ResultDesc>Hi</ResultDesc>
        </Result>
    </LGOResponse>
```

I saw examples for clients that use SoapVar and str_replace and it didnt work for me. Any other ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked...

I replaced return tag with result tag and removed the types:

```
    <?php

    class result extends stdClass
    {
        public $ResultCode = '';
        public $ResultDesc = '';
    }

    class answer
    {
      function lgi($a) {
      $data = new result();
      $data->ResultCode = '0';
      $data->ResultDesc = 'Hi';

      return $data;
    }
    }

    $options = array(
    'uri' => 'http://loooloo.com/LGI',
    'location' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    );
    $soap = new SoapServer(null, $options);
    $soap->setclass("answer");

    ob_start();
    $soap->handle();
    $soap1 = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $soap1 = str_replace("<return xsi:type=\"SOAP-ENC:Struct\">", '<Result>', $soap1);
   $soap1 = str_replace("xsi:type=\"xsd:int\"", '', $soap1);
   $soap1 = str_replace("xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"", '', $soap1);
   $soap1 = str_replace("</return>", '</Result>', $soap1);

   echo $soap1;
```